# Path not found after copieng files

Tags: arraylist, vbscript, file-copying

A list and a target path are passed to a procedure.
The list contains the source paths of the files to be copied.
The For loop runs over the list and passes the source path together with the target path of the vbscript functions CopyFile.

```vb
Sub CopyFilesToFolder(ByVal fileList, ByVal path)
    Dim objFSO
    Dim tmpItem

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    DBWMsgBox fileList.Count

    For i = 0 To fileList.Count - 1
        tmpItem = fileList.Item(i)
        MsgBox tmpItem & vbCrLf & path
        objFSO.CopyFile tmpItem, path
        MsgBox "Stop1"
    Next

    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

It works for all elements but for the last element I get a message that the path cannot  be found. All files are copied.
The msgbox after the copyfile function works and then I get the following message.

> Message: Source: 'Runtime error in Microsoft VBScript' Line: 440 Char:
>   2 Error: 0 'The path was not found.'
>   -v

The values for the line and char dont match. The procedure start on line 414 and ends on 433.

The script is called via our PDM system. I don't think it's the PDM system because other scripts work fine.

**This is a output of the copyfile function for all files in the list:**

> objFSO.CopyFile S:**************\8-30061\8-30061-0369.DXF, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\
>
> objFSO.CopyFile S:**************\8-28091\8-28091-1431.DXF, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\
>
> objFSO.CopyFile S:**************\8-12141\8-12141-6853.DXF, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\
>
> objFSO.CopyFile s:**************\8-12121\8-12121-0673.PDF, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\
>
> objFSO.CopyFile S:**************\8-30061\8-30061-0369.PDF, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\
>
> objFSO.CopyFile S:**************\8-28091\8-28091-1431.PDF, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\
>
> objFSO.CopyFile S:**************\8-12141\8-12141-6853.PDF, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\
>
> objFSO.CopyFile S:**************\8-12121\8-12121-0673.XLS, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\
>
> objFSO.CopyFile S:**************\8-30061\8-30061-0369.XLS, C:\Users*******\Desktop\8-12121-0673_Gesamt_DXF-PDF-XLS\

Comment: Any chance for a blank entry in the list?

Comment: I dont thin so. The list have 9 elements and 9 files are copied.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. You are right SearchAndResQ. The list 10 elements not 9. The last element ist a blank entry. Thank you. I was blind. :-D